# What considerations Do You have about my PLSQL package?

Tags: oracle, function, stored-procedures, plsql, package

I had a little doubts about my code but yesterday I finally understood some points about to how to start coding my final package project. I share this code with the purpose if You want suggest me some change to perform or anything about my package I will appreciate you.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY emp_upd_pkg IS

  -- Function to update commission of employee --
  FUNCTION comm_upd(
    p_empid employees.employee_id%TYPE)
    RETURN employees.commission_pct%TYPE
  IS
  v_oldcomm employees.commission_pct%TYPE;
  v_newcomm employees.commission_pct%TYPE;
BEGIN
  -- Valid parameter --
  SELECT commission_pct
  INTO   v_oldcomm
  FROM   employees
  WHERE  employee_id = p_empid;

  IF
    v_oldcomm IS NOT NULL THEN
      UPDATE    employees
      SET       commission_pct = commission_pct * 1.1
      WHERE     employee_id    = p_empid
      RETURNING commission_pct
      INTO      v_newcomm;

      RETURN    v_newcomm;
  ELSE
    /*UPDATE    employees
    SET       commission_pct = 0.1
    WHERE     employee_id    = p_empid
    RETURNING commission_pct
    INTO      v_newcomm;

    RETURN    v_newcomm;*/
    RETURN (0);
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
       RETURN (0);
  END comm_upd;

  -- Function to update salary of employee --
  FUNCTION sal_upd(
    p_empid employees.employee_id%TYPE)
  RETURN employees.salary%TYPE
  IS
  v_oldsal   employees.salary%TYPE;
  v_newsal   employees.salary%TYPE;
BEGIN
  -- Valid parameter --
  SELECT salary
  INTO   v_oldsal
  FROM   employees
  WHERE  employee_id = p_empid;

  IF
    v_oldsal IS NOT NULL THEN
      UPDATE    employees
      SET       salary      = salary + 100
      WHERE     employee_id = p_empid
      RETURNING salary
      INTO      v_newsal;

      RETURN v_newsal;
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
       RETURN (0);
  END sal_upd;

  -- Procedure to update comm and sal using package functions --
  PROCEDURE commsal_upd(
    p_empid employees.employee_id%TYPE)
  IS
    v_newcomm employees.commission_pct%TYPE;
    v_newsal  employees.salary%TYPE;
  BEGIN
    -- Call package functions to update sal and comm of all employees --
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(comm_upd(p_empid));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sal_upd(p_empid));

    -- Query for final inform --
    SELECT commission_pct, salary
    INTO   v_newcomm, v_newsal
    FROM   employees
    WHERE  employee_id = p_empid;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('THE NEW COMMISSION FOR EMPLOYEE' || p_empid ||
      ' IS ' || v_newcomm || ' AND THE NEW SALARY IS ' || v_newsal);
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO EXISTE EMPLEADO INGRESADO');
  END commsal_upd;

END emp_upd_pkg;
```

Also, I have a little question: When I do use of a function within a procedure, Can I restringe the "RETURN" sentence of the function with the propuse of only send to call Procedure information?

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  CURSOR cur_empid IS
    SELECT employee_id
    FROM   employees;
  TYPE empid_rec IS RECORD(
    p_empid employees.employee_id%TYPE);
  empid empid_rec;
BEGIN
  FOR empid IN cur_empid LOOP
    emp_upd_pkg.commsal_upd(empid.employee_id);
    EXIT WHEN cur_empid%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

When I use a simple record to update all employees I receive in console information about RETURN info of functions and info about DBMS... of procedure. Can I change my code to receive only Procedure information on console? Thanks!.

```
0
24100
THE NEW COMMISSION FOR EMPLOYEE100 IS  AND THE NEW SALARY IS 24100
0
17100
THE NEW COMMISSION FOR EMPLOYEE101 IS  AND THE NEW SALARY IS 17100
0
17100
THE NEW COMMISSION FOR EMPLOYEE102 IS  AND THE NEW SALARY IS 17100
0
9100
```

Comment: It seems this question is more suitable on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). There are a lot of problems in your code: you don't need select+update - just use single update and "query for final inform" seems redundand

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know about this section. Thanks for your comment.